# Trigonometric functions in Sass -- preprocessor error

Tags: css, sass, compiler-errors, trigonometry

Unfortunately, I think I misunderstand how to use trigonometric functions in Sass. I've done a fair amount of google search, but with limited results.

In order to animate the transition of an HTML element I have code similar to the following in one of my scss files:

```
#home-positions { 
  transform: translateX(200px * sin(45deg));
}
```

When my Sass is compiling, however, I get the following error:

```
Syntax error: Undefined operation: "200px times sin(45deg)".
```

It is very liking I am missing something fundamental, probably pretty simple, and syntactic. Unfortunately, I've looked at a bunch of examples of trigonometric function uses in Sass, though, and I haven't been able to spot the difference between my code, and that in the examples.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution is extracted from *[Trigonometry In Sass](https://unindented.org/articles/trigonometry-in-sass/)* by Daniel Perez Alvarez.

> ```
> /* power */
> @function pow($number, $exp) {
>   $value: 1;
>   @if $exp > 0 {
>     @for $i from 1 through $exp {
>       $value: $value * $number;
>     }
>   }
>   @else if $exp < 0 {
>     @for $i from 1 through -$exp {
>       $value: $value / $number;
>     }
>   }
>   @return $value;
> }
>
> /* factorial */
> @function fact($number) {
>   $value: 1;
>   @if $number > 0 {
>     @for $i from 1 through $number {
>       $value: $value * $i;
>     }
>   }
>   @return $value;
> }
>
> /* pi */
> @function pi() {
>   @return 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971694;
> }
>
> /* radian */
> @function rad($angle) {
>   $unit: unit($angle);
>   $unitless: $angle / ($angle * 0 + 1);
>   // If the angle has 'deg' as unit, convert to radians.
>   @if $unit == deg {
>     $unitless: $unitless / 180 * pi();
>   }
>   @return $unitless;
> }
>
> /* sine */
> @function sin($angle) {
>   $sin: 0;
>   $angle: rad($angle);
>   // Iterate a bunch of times.
>   @for $i from 0 through 10 {
>     $sin: $sin + pow(-1, $i) * pow($angle, (2 * $i + 1)) / fact(2 * $i + 1);
>   }
>   @return $sin;
> }
> ```

And then eventually

```
 #home-positions { 
   transform: translateX(200px * sin(45deg));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To anyone confused by this in the future, Sass itself, as of 11/17/14 does not support trigonometric functions. Instead, the [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) framework is required to use them. (See this [article](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass) for step-by-step instructions on installing compass.)

Answer (score 0):

Or just

```
$sin45deg: .7071;
```

Then replace `sin(45deg)` with `$sin45deg`. Tada, no framework needed.